# Effect of Deadcat frame on performance?

Tags: performance, drone-frame

I've seen a lot of new frames with a Deadcat style because it keeps the props out of view for cinematic videos and such. Does the Deadcat shape of frame have any effects on flight performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally have never used a Deadcat frame, but I found this [forum thread](https://intofpv.com/t-deadcat-framedesign-compared-to-others) asking a similar question, the answer is:

> I was more interested in how the dynamics of a dead cat might affect efficiency.  But based on what some of the long-range guys have found, **it doesn't appear to be an issue**.  One thing that did come up with the SG+ at its genesis was instability while in steep dives, like down cliff faces, etc.  Guys were setting up in BF as a straight X design.  Once they started setting up as a custom in BF and used the program that Project Blue Falcon explains, the instability went away.